# Multiple Authentication Laravel - Socialite Plugin

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've implemented multiple authentication in my Laravel application and I have two different tables to accomplish this task (users and clients).

Everything works fine, the the only issue I've met is related to social authentication. I've followed all the configuration about *Socialite-plugin* but I don't know how to set up the redirect URL depending on wich type of user (users or clients) is trying to log in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How you check if user is user or client?

You can add extra parameter to redirect route

```
Route::get('auth/{type}/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirect')
```

(where {type} is user type)

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I've already different routes for clients and users and also different controllers to manage authentication. The issue is related the to "redirect" parameter that should be setted in "services.php" file according socialite-plugin configuration (and in .env file as well). I would be able to change this uri depending on user-type that is trying to login

Comment: 'facebook' => [
        'client_id' =>  env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT'),
    ],

Comment: I refererred to the section above

Comment: You can create middleware to redirect route. If user is a client you can override this FACEBOOK_REDIRECT environment variable by putenv().

Comment: I've tryied to set env variable in social section of auhtentication controllers (both for users and clients). It seemed working well but probably values' variable get cached, so when I set its for the first time they don't change till I restart the server.

Comment: Ok, can you ignore .env settings? Try replace `'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT')` with `'redirect' => 'default-value'`, then in auth controller you can do this `config(['services.facebook.redirect' => 'custom-redirect-url'])`

Comment: Even this solution doesn't work. There is something wrong 'cause it seems to run controller method basing on redirect value setted in services.php (it's what you called "default-value"): e.g. if I set in services.php that value to be right for users it always run users controller method (I've already checked routes in my views and in routes.php file)

Comment: Furthermore, if I set in my controller a redirect value different (using config function) from that one setted in services.php file it throws the following error: "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you  (truncated...)". I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @user51713 did you find any solution for this?